# What's the meaning of "ding on the head"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I'm an English learner and I read this news below:

> Concussion? Oh, got a little ding on the head, no, no you can't play for the rest of the season. Our people are tough! Trump said.

What's the meaning of "ding on the head"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, *ding* is synonymous with *injury*, possibly *bruise*, in this case. It's just an extension of the following:

> [ding](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ding) noun [ C ] (DAMAGE)
>   ​US a small damaged area on a surface where something has hit it:
>   She had the ding in the paintwork repaired.
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

In my opinion, it's a colloquial usage. *On the head* is literal. In other words, Trump is literally saying the person has a small injury on their head. This is an inaccurate description as the injury ([concussion](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/concussion/symptoms-causes/syc-20355594)) does not occur on the surface of the head, but rather within the head. Also note that he's minimizing the severity of the injury.

Comment: Ohh I see! Very clear detailed, appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Sure thing :) But please, on this site, you thank users by up voting their answers, or accepting them (clicking the check mark ✓). However, please **do not** immediately accept the first answer you receive. We suggest waiting at least 12-24 hours before accepting an answer. See [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) for an explanation. Note that your check mark is visible immediately, but your up votes will not be visible until you reach 15 reputation.

Comment: Also see the [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more tips.

Comment: haha okay, thx again!